# Using pip modules in python Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip

I am having trouble using installed packages on my mac. I have attached a picture with my terminal as well as my code.

[image: Terminal and Code]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `pip install pandas`

Comment: when i do that it says it is already installed, but when i run the program it does not work

Comment: `pip3 install pandas`. BTW, best to post the output of the error message as text, not a screen shot.

Comment: I get the same error when trying this too.

Comment: As macOS only ships with Python 2.7, you must have installed Python 3 yourself, so you need to say how you installed Python 3 or else no-one can help you without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

you can check installed packages using command `pip freeze`.

it's seems like `pandas` package not installed. so you can install `pip install pandas`

`pip --version` can check your pip version and check python version (2 or 3).

Answer (score 0):

## Running with Python 3 Framework

You have to make sure you have the proper Python 3 packages installed.

```
pip3 install pandas
pip3 install quandl
```

Then try running your script again. Looks like you are installing Python 2 packages (see the ...`Versions/2.7`... in the output.

You can try `which pip` to see which `pip` application is being run and check its version with `pip --version`.

---

## Running with `conda`

Conda serves as a package manager (similar to `pip`) as well as a virtual environment (similar to `virtualenv` [`virtualenv` docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)). If you are running in a `conda` environment, you should install package dependencies with `conda` (not `pip`).

### Installing Dependencies with `conda`

With `conda` you can install your package dependencies when you first create a Python environment:

```
conda create -n my_env pandas quandl
```

Or you can add packages to an already existing environment:

```
conda install -n my_env2 pandas quandl
```

### Conda Solution

1. make a new `conda` environment

`conda create my_solution pandas quandl`

2. activate that environment

`source activate my_solution`

`# verify it's activated (should have * by it; don't type $)`
`$ conda info --envs`

`# conda environments:`
`#`
`my_solution           *  /Users/{name}/anaconda3/envs/my_solution`
`root                     /Users/{name}/anaconda3`

3. execute your script

`$ python linear-regression.py`

```
              Open    High     Low    Close      Volume  Ex-Dividend  \
Date
2004-08-19  100.01  104.06   95.96  100.335  44659000.0          0.0
2004-08-20  101.01  109.08  100.50  108.310  22834300.0          0.0
2004-08-23  110.76  113.48  109.05  109.400  18256100.0          0.0
2004-08-24  111.24  111.60  103.57  104.870  15247300.0          0.0
2004-08-25  104.76  108.00  103.88  106.000   9188600.0          0.0

            Split Ratio  Adj. Open  Adj. High   Adj. Low  Adj. Close  \
Date
2004-08-19          1.0  50.159839  52.191109  48.128568   50.322842
2004-08-20          1.0  50.661387  54.708881  50.405597   54.322689
2004-08-23          1.0  55.551482  56.915693  54.693835   54.869377
2004-08-24          1.0  55.792225  55.972783  51.945350   52.597363
2004-08-25          1.0  52.542193  54.167209  52.100830   53.164113

            Adj. Volume
Date
2004-08-19   44659000.0
2004-08-20   22834300.0
2004-08-23   18256100.0
2004-08-24   15247300.0
2004-08-25    9188600.0
```

NOTE: In your script, I changed all refs to `Quandl` to `quandl`.

Comment: Please post the result of the error as text so we can see it. :)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linear-regression.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: this was after i have tried both pip install pandas, as well as, pip3 install pandas

Comment: Please post result of `pip3 --freeze`.

Comment: MacBook:Desktop danhessler$ pip3 freeze
backports.weakref==1.0rc1
bleach==1.5.0
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
gym==0.9.2
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.5
inflection==0.3.1
Markdown==2.6.8
matplotlib==2.0.2
more-itertools==3.2.0
numpy==1.12.1
olefile==0.44
pandas==0.20.3
Pillow==4.2.1
protobuf==3.3.0
pyglet==1.2.4
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
Quandl==3.2.0
requests==2.17.3
scikit-learn==0.19.0
scipy==0.19.1
six==1.10.0
sklearn==0.0
tensorflow==1.2.1
tflearn==0.3.2
urllib3==1.21.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2

Comment: Are you using conda?